# How to intersect multiple queries using MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to intersect these queries. I am going to have from two intersecting queries to five intersecting queries.

```
select * from Main
left join title_keyword_link on Main.id = title_keyword_link.title_id
left join keywords_master on title_keyword_link.keyword_id = keywords_master.id
where keywords_master.keyword = 'opinion'

INTERSECT 

select * from Main
left join title_keyword_link on Main.id = title_keyword_link.title_id
left join keywords_master on title_keyword_link.keyword_id = keywords_master.id
where keywords_master.keyword = 'sports'
```

I found out MYSQL does not support INTERSECT, so I tried some of the suggested alternatives. I tried:

```
select * from Main
left join title_keyword_link on Main.id = title_keyword_link.title_id
left join keywords_master on title_keyword_link.keyword_id = keywords_master.id
where keywords_master.keyword in ( 'opinion', 'sports')
```

^This shows results that look more like a UNION of opinion and sports

I also tried:

```
select keywords from Main
left join title_keyword_link on Main.id = title_keyword_link.title_id
left join keywords_master on title_keyword_link.keyword_id = keywords_master.id
where keywords_master.keyword = 'sports'
and keywords_master.keyword  in (select keywords from Main
    left join title_keyword_link on Main.id = title_keyword_link.title_id
    left join keywords_master on title_keyword_link.keyword_id = keywords_master.id
    where keywords_master.keyword = 'opinion')
```

^This code causes MySQL Workbench to crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get rows from `Main` that are related to both keywords 'opinion' and 'sports', I would use a query like this:

```
  SELECT m.*
    FROM Main m
    JOIN ( SELECT k.title_id
             FROM title_keyword_link k
             JOIN keywords_master r
               ON r.id = k.keyword_id
            WHERE r.keyword IN ('opinion','sports')  -- specific keywords to search for
            GROUP BY k.title_id 
           HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r.keyword) = 2      -- number of keywords to match
         ) s
      ON s.title_id = m.id                           -- only return rows that match
```

An equivalent result can be obtained using an "`EXISTS (correlated subquery)`" pattern:

```
  SELECT m.*
    FROM Main m
   WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                    FROM title_keyword_link k1
                    JOIN keywords_master r1
                      ON r1.id = k1.keyword_id
                   WHERE r1.keyword = 'opinion' -- keyword 1 to search for 
                     AND k1.title_id = m.id     -- matches row in outer query
                )
     AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                    FROM title_keyword_link k2
                    JOIN keywords_master r2
                      ON r2.id = k2.keyword_id
                   WHERE r2.keyword = 'sports'  -- keyword 2 to search for
                     AND k2.title_id = m.id     -- matches row in outer query
                )
```

Those example queries will return a resultset, all the rows in `Main` that are associated with both 'opinion' and 'sports' keywords.

But neither of those two example queries answers the question that was asked:

---

**Q:** "How to intersect multiple queries"

**A:** It is possible to get an "intersection" of the results returned by two (or more) queries in MySQL. In some cases, we can emulate the missing `INTERSECT` set operator using an INNER JOIN operation of inline views.

For the specific query as shown in the question, it's *not* possible to use that *exact* query as an inline view, because the query returns multiple columns with the same name. (The root of the problem is the `select *`, with both the `Main` table and the `keywords_master` table contain a column named `id`. The query would need to be modified so that it returns only distinct column names.)

We also note that in the OP query, the "outerness" of the LEFT JOIN operations is negated by the predicate in the WHERE clause. The result returned from that query will be equivalent to results returned using inner join operations.

Comment: Thanks! This answer will be valuable as I intersect more keywords. Also faster!

Comment: For non-trivial sets, with suitable indexes available on the tables, both of the queries should be *much* faster than a join operation on two (or more) derived tables. Also, if these were my queries, I would replace `SELECT m.*` with a list of specific expressions to be returned...  e.g. `SELECT m.id, m.title, LEFT(m.foo,40) AS foo FROM`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use an inner join between the two result table

```
  select * from (

select Main.id from Main
left join title_keyword_link on Main.id = title_keyword_link.title_id
left join keywords_master on title_keyword_link.keyword_id = keywords_master.id
where keywords_master.keyword = 'opinion'

  ) t1 
 inner join (
    select Main.id from Main
    left join title_keyword_link on Main.id = title_keyword_link.title_id
    left join keywords_master on title_keyword_link.keyword_id = keywords_master.id
    where keywords_master.keyword = 'sports'
  ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: The query (as shown, with the `select *` in the inline view queries) will likely throw error 1060, since both the `Main` table and `keywords_master` table contain a column named `id`.

Comment: It did throw error 1060, but I am working around that.

Comment: The update was not my final answer, but it lead me to my final answer. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

By intersect, do you mean Cartesian product?

Where do you want to intersect the tables?

I'm thinking of a LEFT JOIN, but you might have to combine LEFT JOIN with other declarations.

Can you do sub queries? You might have to combine sub queries with LEFT JOIN.

Comment: This is not an answer. Earn the rep and comment anywhere. Answers aren't for chatter

Comment: Not a lot of experience with SQL, but when I say intersect, I mean different queries and keep the output that match. Example set A Intersect set B. A = [1, 2, 3, 4]. B = [2, 4, 5]. A intersect B = [2, 4].